# How do I write if ''not'' in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
el("inp").onpropertychange=function(){
    addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q="+this.value);
};
```

I want to exclude the arrow keys. As I understand I can do this with `if (!(condition)) {action}`  But how do I write this in the code above?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to replace the angle brackets in this.value before passing it to google?

Comment: Im talking about the up and down keys

Comment: If you want to disable the autocomplete feature on text inputs, just use HTML attribute `<input autocomplete=off>`.

Comment: @duri  No, I want to disable the arrow keys in the code above.

Comment: `event.propertyName` should tell you the property that is being changed and triggering the event.  Which property do arrows keys change in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you can simply replace the angle brackets in the `this.value` string with an empty string.

```
var query = this.value.replace(">","").replace("<","");
```

Comment: I mean arrow keys  as in keyCode==40 and keyCode==38, the up and down keys. The point is they are doing stuff and I don't want them to do anything. So I have to do something like this '!keyCode==40'

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Are you trying to kill autocomplete?

Comment: I have a suggestions list which has an event onkeyup, unfortunately in IE8 the arrow keys ALSO trigger the event, so I want to cancel the event IF an arrow key is being pressed.

Comment: @Youss Are you using keyup or onpropertychange?

Comment: @ Dennis I'm using onpropertychange, onkeyup doesn't work in IE8